# How to show an image in a popup on click

Tags: jquery, html

I am having a simple accordion which has three divs Category One,Category Two,Category Three.All the three divs have some images , whaT i want to achieve is that when I click on any image from the accordion , that image should be displayed in a popup with its height width increased.Can any one help me out.Any help is much appreciated.Thanks.

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SzR6h/6/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a fiddle without any help of a plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/SzR6h/25/

**Answer to your comment**

Assume that your bigger images have a completely different name, I'd put that name in a data-*-Attribute in the image tag, e.g.

```
<img src="http://0.s3.envato.com/files/19320511/Scenery%2080x80%20Avatar.png"
data-image-big="url_to_image_big"/>
```

In your javaScript, you can then get image URL by writing:

```
var urlBigImage = $img.data('image-big');
```

Comment: great worked well thanks for that, one question to you , suppose instead of increasing height and width of the image , I needed to open the same image of different size , then how do I go about it , should I need to point it in href of a tag.thanks.

Comment: thanks that I should add something like that , and the attribute is data right?? you wrote data-image-big , was bit confusing

Comment: Sorry, thought you knew about it. Have a look here: http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

Comment: great got it now , thanks for the help.The jquery website seems to be a great place for sharpening my jquery skills , thanks

Comment: Yes. Another good option is to go trough existing stackoverflow questions regarding jquery.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called a Lightbox. "Fancybox" it is a jQuery Lightbox plugin.

You can find that plugin over here:
http://fancybox.net

There is plenty of good documentation about it too and it is very simple to use: http://fancybox.net/howto

---

**Example:**

You just have to include all .js and .css files and modify your HTML a little bit:

```
<a class="my_images" href="bigimage.jpg">
    <img src="thumbnail.jpg" alt=""/>
</a>
```

Then you add the Fancybox:

```
$("a.my_images").fancybox();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use some lightbox plugin like:
http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Answer (score 0):

You can use any light box plugin. Many of them is available out there, Here is a demo using http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/SzR6h/12/)

Add the big image's url in `href` of `a` and add a class like `colorbox`, then include necessary files and initialize colorbox like

**HTML**

```
<a class="colorbox" href="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
   <img src="http://0.s3.envato.com/files/19320511/Scenery%2080x80%20Avatar.png"/>
</a>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('a.colorbox').colorbox({photo:true});
```

Comment: thanks will try that link , that means in the href of my a tag I need to point to  the same image right.

Comment: @freebird Yeah, larger version's link of same image, or a different image if you want. It will show what you put in `href`.

Comment: thanks for all this , one last thing , i have seen many plugins demo , they show some loading gif and then show image , will it possible for you to help me out with this.thanks a lot.

Comment: Colorbox will handle that automatically, check http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example5/, click on any of the link and see it will show a loading image, while loading the image.